# Understanding `null` with Oracle Function's IF-Statement

Tags: oracle

Given the following Oracle function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION nullFunction(a NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  varX NUMBER;
  BEGIN
  select 1 into varX from dual where exists(select 1 from dual where a = 1);
    IF (varX = 1) THEN RETURN 1;
                  ELSE RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Then, I called it from a Oracle SQL Developer's worksheet:

`select nullFunction(3) from dual` returns `(null)`.

Next, I modified my function to:

```
create or replace FUNCTION nullFunction(a NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  varX NUMBER;
  BEGIN
  select 1 into varX from dual where exists(select 1 from dual where a = 1);
    IF (varX is NULL) THEN RETURN 0;
                      ELSE RETURN 1;
    END IF;
  END;
```

But, I received the same output when calling it with a value of `3` - `null`.

Why does it return `NULL`? I would've expected it to have returned `0` since `varX`, which I'm assuming to be equal to `null`, as part of the `else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass any number except the number 1 then your select returns no data and raises a no_data_found exception.  Not sure what you are wanting to do but a simple solution would be to add an exception.

```
create or replace FUNCTION nullFunction(a NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
varX NUMBER;
BEGIN
select 1 into varX from dual where exists(select 1 from dual where a = 1);
 RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
RETURN 0;

END;
```

Alternatively restructure the select from dual so that it cannot return a no_data_found.

Comment: `Alternatively restructure the select from dual so that it cannot return a no_data_found.` How would I do that?

Comment: `If you pass any number except the number 1 then your select returns no data and raises a no_data_found exception`. But, running `select 1 from dual where (select 1 from dual where exists( select 1 from dual where 1 = 0)) is null` returns `1`, indicating the the inner `EXISTS` clause evaluates to `NULL`, not an exception, no?

Comment: @KevinMeredith - as David has said above - it would be helpful to know what the function is supposed to do and under what conditions.

Comment: The PL/SQL block is interested in what the SELECT statement returned, not how it evaluated it. The SELECT returns no data and therefore the PL/SQL raises the NO_DATA_FOUND exception (which isn't trapped by your code).

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Re: How would I do that? – `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(...) THEN 1 END INTO varX FROM DUAL;`

Comment: To add, NO_DATA_FOUND isn't an error for a SQL statement, so when the query "select nullFunction(3) from dual" is executed, you only see the null value in the selected column. Similar to "UPDATE table SET col=(select 1 from DUAL where 1=2)" will put a null value in the column.